# Notification of intention to fix build in TFS

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, build-process, azure-devops

I seem to remember some time in a previous job I was in their continuous integration service was Cruise Control with CCTray for notifications.

When a build failed a notification was sent out (appearing in the notification tray) to likely candidates who had recently checked in code. It was then possible to click on the notification and 'volunteer' to fix the build. A new notification was then automatically sent out to the previous recipients so that it was known that someone was on the case.

I was wondering if this sort of functionality is in TFS.

At the moment we use automatic e-mails in TFS to achieve the first part (notification of failed builds) but it would be really useful if it is possible to volunteer and send automatic replies (or something) to those on the 'failure candidates' list so that it is known that the failed build is in the process of being fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a TFS Build will create a Work Item when it fails (a bug WI I think).  You can indicate your intention to fix the build by assigning the work item to you and/or updating the state as necessary.

[image]

Comment: Whilst this is as close as it comes, it's still not as nice as the CC tray feature. I suppose it'd be possible to build some sort of status panel that does the grunt work of retrieving the linked work item, grabbing the name (if anyone had self-assigned it), and then displaying that somehow (whether it's a tray icon, or status page). Ideally, it'd be associated with the build itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Catlight build notification tool](https://catlight.io).

For a broken build, one of the developers can click on "I will investigate", and every other team member can see it through this app. For more details, take a look a [this blog post](http://blog.catlight.io/post/144836050563/build-investigations).

[image]